# Injecting @EJB in OmniFaces @Eager bean causes "Severe: No valid EE environment for injection of org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository"

Tags: glassfish, ejb, cdi, eager-loading, omnifaces

Using `@ApplicationScoped @Named @Eager`, my `@EJB`-injected `@Stateless` beans are not properly instantiated and evaluate to `null`.

I had an `@ApplicationScoped @ManagedBean(eager=true)` that was used to schedule a few jobs. Some `@Stateless` beans were injected using `@EJB` annotation, and that worked fine.

In the move to CDI annotations, I added the [OmniFaces `@Eager`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Eager) annotation as substitute for `@ManagedBean(eager=true)` which is missing in standard CDI:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.Eager;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
@Eager
public class MyScheduler implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private MyService myService;
    @Inject
    private MyNamedBean myNamedBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setupSchedulers();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        destroySchedulers();
    }
    //...
}
```

Using this setup, the `@PostConstruct` method is correctly called on application startup (though it seems to run even before the context is initialized), but then `myService` evaluates to `null`.

In the log, the following warnings appear:

```
Severe:   No valid EE environment for injection of org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository
Severe:   No valid EE environment for injection of my.package.MyScheduler
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) for context '/tagific'
```

Since I need to access this bean from other ones, I couldn't use the `@Singleton` and `@Schedule` annotations.

How could I properly inject `@Stateless` beans in an `@Named` applications scoped bean that would be instantiated on application startup?

Comment: Which container impl/version? Works for me at WildFly 8.1. As alternative, try `@Inject` instead of `@EJB` (should normally work by the way).

Comment: I'm using glassfish 4.0, Mojarra 2.2.8. Using @Inject resolved the issue. Please add an answer I can accept. Would be nice if you could explain why `@EJB` didn't work and the missing EE context in the logs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an initialization ordering bug in GlassFish. The `@Eager @ApplicationScoped` runs in a `ServletContextListener`. Apparently at that point GlassFish hasn't EJBs ready for injection. This construct works in e.g. WildFly.

However, in CDI's name of unifying various different depency injection approaches throughout Java EE, you can also just use `@Inject` instead of `@EJB`. The CDI proxy is capable of delegating further to the right `@Stateless` instance.

```
@Inject
private MyService myService;
```

You can also use `@Inject` inside EJBs itself, but as of now (Java EE 7) it doesn't yet support self-referencing for e.g. `@Asynchronous` methods. For that you have still to stick to `@EJB`.

---

That said, are you aware that Oracle stopped commercial support on GlassFish and that you'd better not use it for production environments? See also [this blog](http://blog.arungupta.me/2013/11/glassfish-commercial-is-dead-wildfly-and-jboss-eap-to-rescue/).